Grant admin consent for app registration API permission
i create a new app registration via MgGraph Powershell Module, for example:
$appName = "Test"
$APIResourceID = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
$APIResourceAccess = @{
        Id="5ac13192-7ace-4fcf-b828-1a26f28068ee"
        Type="Role"
    }
$app = New-MgApplication -DisplayName $appName `
    -PasswordCredentials @{ displayName="Secret Name" } `
    -RequiredResourceAccess @{ ResourceAppId=$APIResourceID; ResourceAccess=@($APIResourceAccess) }

This works, i get an app registration with the API permission "DeviceManagementServiceConfig.ReadWrite.All" but it still requires the admin consent within Entra ID. I know that there is a way to grant the admin consent via Powershell within the Azure Module "az ad app permission admin-consent --id $app.id" but i'd like to stay within MgGraph. I searched a lot, but cant find a way to grant the admin consent with MgGraph, is it just noch possible yet?
checked the documentations but found only ways to grant delegated permissions or application permissions with MgServicePrincipal

You have to make use of MgServicePrincipal commands to grant admin consent to delegated permissions or application permissions

Create the Service Principal for the Application and then use this script to Grant admin consent to application permissions

@Rukmini i've extended the script to your suggestions:
..
$servicePrincipal = New-MgServicePrincipal -AppId $app.AppId
$params = @{
principalID = "OBJECT ID OF MY ADMIN USER"
resourceId = $servicePrincipal.Id
appRoleId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedTo -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipal.Id -BodyParameter $params
I can see it with "get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedTo" admin consent is still required from Entra Portal. I got the principalID and appRoleId from another app registration where i did the consent in Entra

The principalID is the Service Principal ID of the application you created and the resourceID is the Microsoft Graph app ID and appRoleId is the permission ID

@Rukmini still dont get it
principalID is easy, just $servicePrincilal.Id.  appRoleId the permission ID, sounds like "5ac13192-7ace-4fcf-b828-1a26f28068ee" for the DeviceManagementServiceConfig.ReadWrite.All permission. But for resourceID i tried $app.id $app.AppID  and the Object and ClientID of the App registration what i've use to conenct to MgGraph, all result in the same error with different IDs of course: New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedTo_Create: Resource 'acabANY ID IVE TRIED495954' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

principalID is the object ID of Service principal not App ID

Can you check the below screenshots to get the correct values?

To grant admin consent to the Application permissions, check the below:
Create the Service principal after creating the application:
New-MgServicePrincipal -AppId <AppIDofappinappregisterationblade>



Now make use of below script to grant admin consent to the Application permissions:
$params = @{
principalId = "SPObjID"
resourceId = "MicrosoftGraphResourceID"
appRoleId = "APIpermissionID"
}
New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedTo -principalId <servicePrincipalId> -BodyParameter $params



To get the values refer below and check this SO Thread by me:
Go to Enterprise application of the application you created:
Copy ObjectID of Enterprise application and pass in it in principalId and principalId values.

The resourceId is the Microsoft Graph Resource ID:
Remove the filters in Enterprise applications blade and search

References:
Grant tenant-wide admin consent to an application delegated permissions - Microsoft Entra ID | Microsoft 
Grant tenant-wide admin consent to an application type permissions - Microsoft Entra ID | Microsoft 

Oh Thank you, finally i just want too stupid to get which Application was meant but it was the default one :D It's working finally :) Thanks for your patience

Glad to know it worked:)
